# Is Ethereum actually something that exists, or is it just a maze of webpages full of nonsense?

Tags: ether, wallets, nodes

I'm trying to be as polite as I can be, as I have nothing against Ethereum specifically. I'm very experienced with Bitcoin, but have never found any other "altcoin" to be worthy the time of day except for possibly Ethereum, since it's been so heavily promoted and mentioned.

The vague claims sound good, but I simply can't find anything of substance on their website. Not for Ethereum 1.0 and not for 2.0. I feel like I'm an alien visiting planet Earth as I try to parse the extremely cryptic messages on the official website.

In particular, there's just no software. I'm not going to use some "phone app", obviously, since that completely violates security in a fundamental way (and I don't own one). The website simply doesn't provide any "download" button for an "Ethereum Core" base application, such as Bitcoin Core for Bitcoin. Not even links to external sites that have such a thing.

I simply can't view this in any other way than this somehow being a big scam of some sort. The dog with the glasses and certain wording around the site also doesn't exactly make me believe that it's too serious. If you compare the Ethereum website with Bitcoin's, it's like night and day in clarity.

I get the feeling that it's not about me downloading a program and starting to use it/become a node. It seems like the idea is to make me use one of numerous third-party centralized exchanges/"Ethereum banks" where I'm going to have to pay them somehow to get Ethereum. And then what?

I honestly am open to this being fully legitimate, and want that to be the case, but I just don't see how.

Can somebody explain what I am missing? Where is the actual THING?

Comment: Ethereum is not user oriented, it is developer oriented. Your developer will tell you were to download the App

Comment: @Nulik "My developer"? The "App"? What?

Comment: (This kind of extremely condescending, hostile, rude comment does not change my view on Ethereum, by the way. Neither does downvoting my question.)

Comment: What are you looking to do with Ethereum? Maybe we can help if you are a bit more specific.

The way you have phrased your question is the same as if somebody would ask "What is this thing called internet? Where is the main website?"

Comment: @RAngstman yeah, the app you are going to be using. In Ethereum we create DAPPs and the end users are using our Apps.  If you don't have an app, and only want to buy some Ether, then you should do it at some exchange

Comment: I want to hold Ether in a fullnode, and be able to create these decentralized applications. I thought that was implied.

Comment: @RAngstman you don't need a full node to hold Ether. You are just going to spend a lot of money on server , bandwidth and storage. This is not going to make your holding more secure. Just buy it at your trading exchange you are using, like kraken or something...

Comment: @RAngstman Gave you some links on my answer

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you're missing a key concept: decentralization.

There is no official anything. There is no official website. There is no official wallet or software or anything. It's a decentralized network where everyone can build whatever tools they want.

Yes, the Ethereum Foundation has a website (which isn't the best) but it's just one of the million websites introducting Ethereum. They don't "own" the network in any way.

So basically you have to do your own research:

- What node client to run (Geth is the most popular one)
- What wallet to use (Metamask browser extension is probably the most popular one)
- What tools to use to create and deploy smart contracts (if you want to do development)

In fact the same should be true for Bitcoin: it should be fully decentralized as well. Now, I really don't know much about Bitcoin, but if it has some "official" things it sounds rather fishy to me.

Comment: I know that it's "decentralized", but in reality, there is an "official" website, just like with Bitcoin. People aren't going to download random executables from some sketchy website.

Answer (score 0):

As you clarified in the comments, you wish to 1) set up a full node 2) hold ether and 3) develop dApps

As to write an answer so extensive would be an over kill I want to link articles that help you do what you need:

- **[Set up a full ethereum node](https://dev.to/eric_khun/a-beginner-guide-to-setup-an-ethereum-full-node-4d9)**
- **[Build your first dApp](https://medium.com/blockchain-at-davis/building-your-first-dapp-a-no-nonsense-guide-d345610c5d62)**

You will need: Geth, Truffle and Metamask.

Good luck.